# Drag and drop without QLineEdit (or at least doesn't require user to highlight the text)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a drag and drop system with blocks of text provided by the code, so I want the user to be able to drag and drop the text boxes for the purpose of placing and reordering some items, but the only way I can see how to do it is using a QLineEdit and making it read only. The issue is, the user still has to highlight the text here, and can highlight only part of it if they wanted. I want to make sure that the user can just click and drag, without highlighting, and has to move the whole box, not just some text inside.

Comment: Do all this also require text editing? Otherwise, you can use a QListWidget and [`setFlow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#flow-prop) with `LeftToRight`.

Comment: @musicamante i will use code and a separate LineEdit to change the text on the drag and drop widgets.
So if I use a ListWidget I can drag and drop the items?

Comment: @musicamante i did as you said, and then set the movement in the list to `free` but not every time i move an item it is duplicating the item